# Computing the Frechet derivative

Tags: derivatives

How does a computation involving the Frechet derivative typically proceed? The definition, $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\| f(x + h) - f(x) - f'(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0$$ seems somewhat cumbersome to use in order to 'solve' for $f'$.

Suppose we consider for example $T \in \mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$ defined by $T = \frac{1}{2}|x|^2x$ or even $T = \mbox{det}:\mathscr{L(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}}$. I'm not certain how to proceed with an explicit calculation for maps like these, though perhaps this is because I have little experience with Frechet differentiation.

Comment: I would start by looking at the form of $f(x+h)-f(x)$ and seeing it that suggests anything. In the case of your first $T$, you may want to consider $x \mapsto \|x\|^2$ first, and then use the product rule. For $\det$, you might want to start with $D \det(I)$ first, then $D \det(A)$ for invertible $A$, then general $A$. If a function is sufficiently smooth (all the above are), you can also compute the partials and used these to define $f'(x)(h)$ above.

Answer (score 1):

Most problems that you will have to deal with are solved by computing the partial derivatives of your given function. In your case, $T(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \frac 1 2 (x_1 ^2 + \dots x_n ^2)$, so $\frac {\partial T} {\partial x_i} = x_i$ and then $T'(p_1, \dots, p_n) = \frac {\partial T} {\partial x_1} (p_1, \dots, p_n) \mathbb d x_1 + \dots + \frac {\partial T} {\partial x_n} (p_1, \dots, p_n) \mathbb d x_n = p_1 \mathbb d x_1 + \dots + p_n \mathbb d x_n$ ($p$ being the point in which we compute the Fréchet derivative $T'(p)$ (also called "*differential*")). The symbols $\mathbb d x_i$ are linear forms acting on vectors according to $\mathbb d x_i (v) = v_i$, i. e. they extract the $i$-th component of a given vector (this is because the differential is a linear form itself, i.e. it takes vectors and returns numbers).

So, in full, $T'(p)(v) = p_1 v_1 + \dots + p_n v_n$. In general, one omits the arguments $p$ and $v$ and simply writes $T' = \mathbb d T = \frac {\partial T} {\partial x_1} \mathbb d x_1 + \dots + \frac {\partial T} {\partial x_n} \mathbb d x_n$.